# onclick event change background-image with fade transition

Tags: jquery, css, background, fade

I'm searching for a trip in jQuery for changing the background-image of the body (or of a 100%-height "wrapper" div) on a click event of a class element, with a cross-fade transition effect.
Is it possible?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> - **DEMO:** https://so.lucafilosofi.com/onclick-event-change-background-image-with-fade-transition

CSS:

```
*{margin:0;padding:0}
html ,body{width:100%;height:100%;margin:0;padding:0;overflow:hidden}
#bg{position:absolute;height:100%;width:100%;margin:0;padding:0;z-index:0}
```

HTML:

```
<div><img id="bg" src="image.jpg" alt="" /></div>
```

JQUERY

```
var images = ["home_photo_welshboy.jpg","home_photo_jam343.jpg"];

$(function() {
    $('.change').click(function(e) {
    var image = images[Math.floor(Math.random()*images.length)];
        $('#bg').parent().fadeOut(200, function() {
            $('#bg').attr('src', 'http://l.yimg.com/g/images/'+image); 
              $(this).fadeIn(200);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Looks nice, but on my system the old image fades out and the new one pops up at once. I think you could better place the new image behind the old one and then fade out the old image, so the new image seems to appear slowly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I can't really see the fade transition effect between an image and another one.
I'm on Firefox 3.6 on a Mac.

Comment: Yes, I think now it works better!
I noticed that you edit the Fade value. Thank you so much, you're very gentle! :)