# Fade In/Out Background Image with Another Image / fade out other elements

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, fadein, fadeout

I'm having trouble with fadein/out of some elements. I need to have several divs, fade in a new background, as well as text when it is hovered over. I also need to have the other divs to fade out some, while I'm hovered over that element.

I can fade out the other elements if I'm hovered over an element, but the rest of the problem I cannot figure out.

I only want those specific divs to be affected as I have other divs (id and classes) on the page.

Here is my fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/deelite/SnvMr/2/

My jquery:

```
$('div').hover(function() {
  $('div').not($(this)).stop().fadeTo(500, 0.33);
  }, function() {
  $('div').stop().fadeTo(500, 1);
});
```

I'm not sure how else to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Mooseman for his help on the code, I took it one step further, on how to do the background "change" by inserting a div (that contains the new background) into the div that contains the first background, and have the new div fade in/out over the old. The second div has to be the same "dimensions" as the original, unless you are going for an effect where the bg's must be offset from each other.

You can view the updated code here:
http://jsfiddle.net/deelite/SnvMr/12/

JS CODE:

```
$('.effect').hover(
function () {
    $('.effect').not(this).stop().fadeTo(500, 0.33);
    $(this).find('div').stop().fadeTo(500, 1);
}, function () {
    $('.effect').stop().fadeTo(500, 1);
    $('.effect div').stop().fadeTo(500, 0);
});
```

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just use `.not(this)`; `.not($(this))` is incorrect. You also had a couple other errors. You can just add another class (e.g., `.effect`) to the the `div`s you want to apply the effect to.

HTML:

```
<div class="effect one"><p>me</p></div>
<div class="effect two"><p>have</p></div>
<div class="effect three"><p>fun</p></div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.effect').hover(
    function() {
        $('.effect').not($(this)).stop().fadeTo(500, 0.33);
    }, function() {
        $('.effect').stop().fadeTo(500, 1);
    }
);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SnvMr/5/

Comment: sorry, had to update the jquery. the new fiddle is in my post.

Comment: thanks, but what about changing the bakcgrounds and showing text on hover?

Comment: thanks. its almost what I have in mind. I actually want the background image to fade in/out because there is a slight flicker if I use the class:hover method.

Comment: @Keoki See another question on Stack Overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2999562/onclick-event-change-background-image-with-fade-transition

Comment: I read through that, and it's not the same as what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Keoki The title has "change background-image with fade transition" and it is tagged jQuery.

Comment: I'm not sure how it applies to what I'm doing however. Can you explain clearly? It has a bunch of images applying to ONE element. I have three elements that needs its own background change. and the demo on that post isn't smooth (its rather flickery in firefox and IE8)